# How to have two widgets in one Main window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying the whole morning already to fix that.
So I have a PyQt Main Window where I want to display two widgets.
In the first widget there are articles listed (which works so far).
When I click on them until now a QMessageBox is opening, but I want that
a second widget is opening where I can read the RSS Feed.
But this is not working. See Code below:

```
class ArticleWidgets(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

        self.setGeometry(610, 610, 600, 600)

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.box = QHBoxLayout(self)

    def show(self, feed=None):

        self.title = QLabel()
        self.summary = QLabel()
        self.link = QLabel()

        if feed:
            self.title.setText(feed[0])
            self.summary.setText(feed[1])
            self.link.setText(feed[2])

        self.box.addWidget(self.title)
        self.box.addWidget(self.summary)
        self.box.addWidget(self.link)

        self.setLayout(self.box)


class TitleWidgets(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

        self.setGeometry(10, 10, 600, 600)

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        vbox = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.titleList = QListWidget()
        self.titleList.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.titleList.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 400)
        self.news = ANFFeed()
        for item in self.news.all_feeds:
            self.titleList.addItem(item[0])
        vbox.addWidget(self.titleList)

    def onClicked(self, item):
        feeds = self.news.all_feeds
        id = 0
        for elem in range(len(feeds)):
            if feeds[elem][0] == item.text():
                id = elem

        summary = feeds[id][1] + '\n\n'
        link = feeds[id][2]

        if feeds and id:
            #ANFApp(self).show_articles(feeds[id])
            show = ANFApp()
            show.show_articles(feed=feeds[id])

        QMessageBox.information(self, 'Details', summary + link)


class ANFApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

        self.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('anf.png'))
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        self.anfInit()

        self.show()

    def anfInit(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('ANF RSS Reader')

        TitleWidgets(self)
        #article_box = ArticleWidgets(self)

        exitBtn = QPushButton(self)
        exitBtn.setGeometry(600, 600, 100, 50)
        exitBtn.setText('Exit')
        exitBtn.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
        exitBtn.clicked.connect(self.exit)

    def show_articles(self, feed=None):
        present = ArticleWidgets()
        present.show(feed)

    def exit(self):
        QCoreApplication.instance().quit()
```

Comment: What class is `ANFFeed()`?

Comment: @AlejandroCondori  An imported class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution using Pyqtgraph's Docks and QTextBrowser

Here is a code trying to reproduce your sketch. I used the `Pyqtgraph` module (Documentation here: [Pyqtgraph's Documentation](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [Pyqtgraph's Web Page](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/)) because its `Dock` widget is easier to use and implement from my perspective.

You must install the `pyqtgraph` module before trying this code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from pyqtgraph.dockarea import *

class DockArea(DockArea):
    ## This is to prevent the Dock from being resized to te point of disappear
    def makeContainer(self, typ):
        new = super(DockArea, self).makeContainer(typ)
        new.setChildrenCollapsible(False)
        return new

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        central_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
    
        label = QtGui.QLabel('This is a label, The widgets will be below')
        label.setMaximumHeight(15)
        ## The DockArea as its name says, is the are where we place the Docks
        dock_area = DockArea(self)
        ## Create the Docks and change some esthetic of them
        self.dock1 = Dock('Widget 1', size=(300, 500))
        self.dock2 = Dock('Widget 2', size=(400, 500))
        self.dock1.hideTitleBar()
        self.dock2.hideTitleBar()
        self.dock1.nStyle = """
        Dock > QWidget {
            border: 0px solid #000;
            border-radius: 0px;
        }"""
        self.dock2.nStyle = """
        Dock > QWidget {
            border: 0px solid #000;
            border-radius: 0px;
        }"""
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Exit')
        self.widget_one = WidgetOne()
        self.widget_two = WidgetTwo()
        ## Place the Docks inside the DockArea
        dock_area.addDock(self.dock1)
        dock_area.addDock(self.dock2, 'right', self.dock1)
        ## The statment above means that dock2 will be placed at the right of dock 1
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(dock_area)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        ## Add the Widgets inside each dock
        self.dock1.addWidget(self.widget_one)
        self.dock2.addWidget(self.widget_two)
        ## This is for set the initial size and posotion of the main window
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)
        ## Connect the actions to functions, there is a default function called close()
        self.widget_one.TitleClicked.connect(self.dob_click)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.close)
        
    def dob_click(self, feed):
        self.widget_two.text_box.clear()
        ## May look messy but wat i am doing is somethin like this:
        ## 'Title : ' + feed[0]  + '\n\n' + 'Summary : ' + feed[1]
        self.widget_two.text_box.setText(
            'Title : ' + feed[0]\
            + '\n\n' +\
            'Summary : ' + feed[1]
        )
        
class WidgetOne(QtGui.QWidget):
    ## This signal is created to pass a "list" when it (the signal) is emited
    TitleClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal([list])
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.titleList = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel('Here is my list:')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.titleList)
        
        self.titleList.addItem(QtGui.QListWidgetItem('Title 1'))
        self.titleList.addItem(QtGui.QListWidgetItem('Title 2'))
        self.titleList.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self, item):
        ## Just test values
        title = item.text()
        summary = "Here you will put the summary of {}. ".format(title)*50
        ## Pass the values as a list in the signal. You can pass as much values
        ## as you want, remember that all of them have to be inside one list
        self.TitleClicked.emit([title, summary]) 

class WidgetTwo(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.label2 = QtGui.QLabel('Here we show results?:')
        self.text_box = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text_box)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Again, there are comments inside the code to help you understand what I did.
Here is how it looks:

[image]

If you pass the mouse between the two widgets you will see the mouse icon will change, with that you can readjust *on the run* the size of both widgets.

### Final Words

This is another approach, more "interactive" and more esthetic than my previous answer. As you said, using a `QSplitter` works too.

Answer (score 1):

### Problems

The way you are building your GUI is, in my opinion, messy and it may lead to errors. I suggest the use of `Layouts` for a more organized GUI.

The other problem is that each widget is an independent class so if you want to connect an action in one widget to do something in the other widget through the Main Window, you must use `Signals`.

**Edit :** Another suggestion, use other name for the close function instead of `exit` and try using `self.close()` instead of `QCoreApplication.instance().quit()`

### Solution

Trying to emulate what you want to do I made this GUI:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        ## Generate the structure parts of the MainWindow
        self.central_widget = QtGui.QWidget() # A QWidget to work as Central Widget
        self.layout1 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout() # Vertical Layout
        self.layout2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout() # Horizontal Layout
        self.widget_one = WidgetOne()
        self.widget_two = WidgetTwo()
        self.exitBtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Exit')
        ## Build the structure
         # Insert a QWidget as a central widget for the MainWindow    
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)  
         # Add a principal layout for the widgets/layouts you want to add
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout1)
         # Add widgets/layuts, as many as you want, remember they are in a Vertical
         # layout: they will be added one below of the other
        self.layout1.addLayout(self.layout2)
        self.layout1.addWidget(self.exitBtn)
         # Here we add the widgets to the horizontal layout: one next to the other
        self.layout2.addWidget(self.widget_one)
        self.layout2.addWidget(self.widget_two)
        ## Connect the signal
        self.widget_one.TitleClicked.connect(self.dob_click)

    def dob_click(self, feed):
        ## Change the properties of the elements in the second widget
        self.widget_two.title.setText('Title : '+feed[0])
        self.widget_two.summary.setText('Summary : '+feed[1])

## Build your widgets same as the Main Window, with the excepton that here you don't
## need a central widget, because it is already a widget.
class WidgetOne(QtGui.QWidget):
    TitleClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal([list]) # Signal Created
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        ## 
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()  # Vertical Layout
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.titleList = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel('Here is my list:')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.titleList)
        
        self.titleList.addItem(QtGui.QListWidgetItem('Title 1'))
        self.titleList.addItem(QtGui.QListWidgetItem('Title 2'))
        self.titleList.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self, item):
        ## Just test parameters and signal emited
        self.TitleClicked.emit([item.text(), item.text()+item.text()]) 

class WidgetTwo(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.title = QtGui.QLabel('Title : ---')
        self.summary = QtGui.QLabel('Summary : ---')
        self.link = QtGui.QLabel('Link : ---')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.title)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.summary)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.link)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Inside the code, there are comments to help you understand why I did to build an organized GUI. There is also an example of a `Signal` being used to connect the action of `itemDoubleClicked` from the first widget to the second one. Here is how the MainWindow looks:

[image]

It is not very clear how the layouts work just from seeing the result, so I did a little paint over to a better understanding:

[image]

The blue box is the vertical layout (`QVBoxLayout`) and the red one is the horizontal layout (`QHBoxLayout`). Inside the blue layout, are located the red layout (above) and the exit button (below); and inside the red layout, are located the widget_1 (left) and the widget_2 (right).

### Other Solution

An "easier" solution will be building the widgets inside the `MainWindow` instead of creating separate classes. With this you will avoid the use of signals, but the code will become a little more confusing because all the code will be cramped in one class.

Comment: Wow, what a detailed post.
Yes I am aware that it is really messy, but it is the first time for me to use PyQt and I was trying a lot so it got more and more messy.
In fact, it is still not what I really wanted to achieve. I wanted to have two widgets like the left one (widget 1) next to each other.
But the exmaple with the Signals was good, I think it is really useful. Thank you so far!

Comment: @m1ghtfr3e You can make your own widget with everything you want inside, and add it in the same way I did. I made the most general example that could emulate what I understood you wanted.

Comment: Ok, I understand, this helps me a lot.
But now I can not really change the size of the widgets, how could I do this?

Comment: @m1ghtfr3e    Layouts manage the size and position of the widgets inside them and readjust the size of the widgets according to the size of the window. It is very convenient if you are constantly changing your window size because it will always "look good". You can add spacers that will stretch some empty areas. Can you send me a sketch (image of the design) of what you want? (to help you more)

Comment: Here is a picture of how I wanted to have the window. I really don't know how I can realize it.
https://pasteboard.co/JKy2PbK.png

Comment: @m1ghtfr3e Perfect, another approach will be the use of Docks, with that you can change the size of the widgets on the run. I will do an example tomorrow and post it as another answer

Comment: I was trying to read through the Usage of Docks but it didn't really work, I think your code would help.
Finally I achieved what I wanted to do with QSplitter.