# How put an image in the upper left corner?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am making an interface in Python, I will put the code part of the buttons, which is what matters for this problem.

I tried to put an image in the upper left corner, but other things of the interface are misconfigured, so I could not program it. Below I will leave an example image.

```
import sys, re
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QMessageBox, QErrorMessage, QToolTip, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QLabel, QTextEdit, QMainWindow, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import ctypes
import pandas as pd

class Dialogo (QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.initUI()
        self.comprasmga.textChanged.connect(self.validar_comprasmga)
        self.setWindowTitle("Python interface")
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow")     
        
    def initUI(self):

        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))
    
        self.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> widget')
        self.setGeometry(350, 320, 1250, 630)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;")
        

        self.btn = QPushButton('Buscar', self)
        self.btn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        self.btn.move(50, 50)
        self.btn.setGeometry(590,70,75,23)

        self.label= QLabel ('Good in Transit', self)
        self.label.setGeometry(850,100,110,20)
        self.label = QLabel ('M3', self)
        self.label.setGeometry(300,100,110,20)
        self.label= QLabel('OOH BPCS',self)
        self.label.setGeometry(850,370,110,20)

        self.comprasmga = QLineEdit(self)
        self.comprasmga.setGeometry(570,40,110,20)
        self.comprasmga.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label = QLabel('Item Number / NP',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(580,20,110,20)


        self.custumer= QTextEdit(self)
        self.custumer.setGeometry(30,180,110,50)
        self.custumer.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label = QLabel ('Custumer´s order number', self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry (30,150, 150,30)
        
        self.itemname= QTextEdit(self)
        self.itemname.setGeometry(180,180,110,50)
        self.itemname.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Item Name',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(200,150,110,30)
        
        self.gac = QTextEdit(self)
        self.gac.setGeometry(330,180,110,50)
        self.gac.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Gac',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(365,150,110,30)
        
        self.orderqty = QTextEdit(self)
        self.orderqty.setGeometry(470,180,110,50)
        self.orderqty.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Order qty',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(495,150,110,30)
        
        self.alocqty = QTextEdit(self)
        self.alocqty.setGeometry(30,270,110,50)
        self.alocqty.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Aloc qty',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(50,240, 150,30)

        self.pickqty= QTextEdit(self)
        self.pickqty.setGeometry(180,270,110,50)
        self.pickqty.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Pick qty',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(200,240, 150,30)
        
        self.delqty= QTextEdit(self)
        self.delqty.setGeometry(330,270,110,50)
        self.delqty.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Del qty',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(350,240, 150,30)
        
        self.invqty= QTextEdit(self)
        self.invqty.setGeometry(470,270,110,50)
        self.invqty.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Inv qty',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(500,240, 150,30)
        
        self.remqty= QTextEdit(self)
        self.remqty.setGeometry(30,355,110,50)
        self.remqty.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Rem qty',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(53,325, 150,30)
        
        self.salesprice= QTextEdit(self)
        self.salesprice.setGeometry(180,355,110,50)
        self.salesprice.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Sales Price',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(200,325, 150,30)
        
        self.status= QTextEdit(self)
        self.status.setGeometry(330,355,110,50)
        self.status.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Status',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(350,325, 150,30)
        
        self.orderdate= QTextEdit(self)
        self.orderdate.setGeometry(470,355,110,50)
        self.orderdate.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Order Date',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(490,325, 150,30)
        
        self.confdeldate= QTextEdit(self)
        self.confdeldate.setGeometry(30,435,110,50)
        self.confdeldate.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Conf. del date',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(40,405, 150,30)
        
        self.lastconfdate= QTextEdit(self)
        self.lastconfdate.setGeometry(180,435,110,50)
        self.lastconfdate.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Last Conf. date',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(200,405, 150,30)
        
        self.firstconfdate= QTextEdit(self)
        self.firstconfdate.setGeometry(330,435,110,50)
        self.firstconfdate.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('First Conf. date',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(350,405, 150,30)
        
        self.newweight= QTextEdit(self)
        self.newweight.setGeometry(470,435,110,50)
        self.newweight.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('New Weight',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(490,405, 150,30)
        
        self.deliverymethod= QTextEdit(self)
        self.deliverymethod.setGeometry(30,515,110,50)
        self.deliverymethod.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Delivery Method',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(40,485, 150,30)
        
        self.departuredate= QTextEdit(self)
        self.departuredate.setGeometry(180,515,110,50)
        self.departuredate.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Departure Date',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(200,485, 150,30)

        self.ordernumber= QTextEdit(self)
        self.ordernumber.setGeometry(330,515,110,50)
        self.ordernumber.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Order Number',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(350,485, 150,30)

        self.yearmonth= QTextEdit(self)
        self.yearmonth.setGeometry(700,180, 110,50)
        self.yearmonth.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label = QLabel ('Año Mes', self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry (720,145, 150,30)
        
        self.gac1 = QTextEdit(self)
        self.gac1.setGeometry(970,180,110,50)
        self.gac1.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Gac',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(1000,145,110,30)
        
        self.purch = QTextEdit(self)
        self.purch.setGeometry(1100,180,110,50)
        self.purch.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Purch',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(1110,145, 150,30)
        
        self.fechattdte= QTextEdit(self)
        self.fechattdte.setGeometry(830,180,110,50)
        self.fechattdte.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Fecha TTDTE',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(850,145, 150,30)
        
        self.key= QTextEdit(self)
        self.key.setGeometry(700,270,190,50)
        self.key.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Llave',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(720,240, 150,30)
        
        self.hord= QTextEdit(self)
        self.hord.setGeometry(700,435,110,50)
        self.hord.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label = QLabel ('Hord', self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry (720,405, 150,30)
        
        self.lqord= QTextEdit(self)
        self.lqord.setGeometry(830,435,110,50)
        self.lqord.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Lqord',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(850,405,110,30)
        
        self.ldesc= QTextEdit(self)
        self.ldesc.setGeometry(970,435,110,50)
        self.ldesc.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Ldesc',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(990,405,110,30)
        
        self.hedte = QTextEdit(self)
        self.hedte.setGeometry(700,515,110,50)
        self.hedte.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Hedte',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(720,485, 150,30)

        self.valooh= QTextEdit(self)
        self.valooh.setGeometry(830,515,110,50)
        self.valooh.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Valooh',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(850,485, 150,30)
        
        self.hcust =QTextEdit(self)
        self.hcust.setGeometry(970,515,110,50)
        self.hcust.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Hcust',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(990,485, 150,30)
        
        self.daysmethod= QTextEdit(self)
        self.daysmethod.setGeometry(1100,435,110,50)
        self.daysmethod.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Days',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(1110,405, 110,30)
        
        self.client =QTextEdit(self)
        self.client.setGeometry(1100,515,110,50)
        self.client.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label= QLabel('Client',self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: yellow;")
        self.label.setGeometry(1110,485, 150,30)

    def validar_comprasmga(self):
        comprasmga = self.comprasmga.text()
        validar = re.match (('^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$')  , comprasmga)
        if comprasmga == "":
            self.comprasmga.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid yellow; ")
            return False
        elif not validar:
            self.comprasmga.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red;")
            return False
        else:
            self.comprasmga.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid green; ")
            return True
        
        
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialogo = Dialogo()
dialogo.show()
app.exec_()
```

Image example:
[image: Image example]

Image example diagram:
[image: Image example diagram]

Comment: You could place an image or diagram of what you want to obtain to understand yourself better

Comment: Yes, thanks you @eyllanesc , I forgot to do it. I already added it

Comment: upper right corner or upper **left** corner?

Comment: I wrote it right now @eyllanesc , thank you. Upper left corner

Comment: "I tried to put an image in the upper left corner, but other things of the interface are misconfigured, so I could not program it": where are you doing it? I cannot see any attempt to add an image. Also, what does "the interface are misconfigured" mean, and why does it matter for the question?

Comment: I deleted it because it did not show what the interface was like, it deconfigured it. I prefer to put a code that shows the interface as it is. I can write it if necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Direct Solution

Create a `QLabel` widget and use `QPixmap to add the picture inside`, then use `setGeometry` to place it on its place. You can add this code inside your `initUI()` method:

```py
   self.image = QLabel(self)
   self.image.setGeometry(10, 10, 160, 100)
   self.pixmap = QPixmap('image_example.png')
   self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
   self.image.setScaledContents(True)
```

`setScaledContents` is to resize the picture to fit entirely in the widget. Don't forget to import `QPixmap`:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
```

[image]

### Suggestion

All the widgets inside your GUI have specific positions and sizes. This becomes a problem when you readjust the size of the window because the widgets inside will not readjust its size. For a better-looking interface and more compatibility with different sizes of screens, try using `layouts`, you can find more information here: [Layout Management](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/layout.html)

Comment: It worked. I will try to learn about "layout management". Thanks a lot uwu

Comment: @cfsl Here is one answer I made using Layouts, it should work as a practical example of what is Layout Management:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65793817/13929529